# Convert integer of MYYYY into Date in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a field that is a bunch of integers formatted like so:

```
92014
102014
```

I would like to convert the field into a `datetime` of the first of each month. So the newly formated field would be:

```
9/01/2014 00:00:00
10/01/2014 00:00:00
```

(or however datetimes would actually get formatted). Can anyone help?

Comment: Use string-parsing functions.   They are well-documented.   Though personally, I would handle this in the SQL rather than an SSRS expression.

Comment: @TabAlleman - This is what i have been currently looking into, however i have not found one that allows me to do this. Any ideas on which one?

Comment: You should be able to do everything you need with LEN() and SUBSTRING().   Using RIGHT() might be even easier though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can accomplish this in an expression:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(IIF(LEN(Trim(Fields!StringDate.Value)) < 6, "0" & Fields!StringDate.Value,Fields!StringDate.Value),"Myyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```